# ssrs subscription multi value - parameter not saved

Tags: reporting-services, subscription

I didn't create the report, but there is a (not data-driven) subscription. There is one parameter with a default value (no issues).  Then there are two multi-value parameters.  When modifying the (mysteriously empty) multi-value parms (after the report failed to run) I can select ALL for each and set to run once--and the process succeeds.  A file is written out to the folder per my intentions.

But when the date to run is set to the next morning, the execution fails with a message about invalid parm values.  When I go in to check, those multi parms are empty again.

- How do I fix this? (dumb question, I know)

  What am I doing wrong? (also, very non-specific)

  What am I leaving out? (of this question)

  How do I search for this issue on SO? (I tried, but I couldn't find anything similar; maybe I'm missing some terminology; my search terms were "**ssrs subscription multi value parameter not saved**")

Comment: Silly question, but did you edit the parameters by going to the subscription and then down to the section for "Report Parameter Values"?  Changing them elsewhere doesn't necessarily impact the subscription.

Comment: yes; I went into the web-based subscription environment to make the change

Comment: Hm.  The box usually shows up blank when there are stored values that aren't in the dropdown, since the page can't display them.  You can check what's literally in there by looking at the "Parameters" column of the "Subscriptions" table for the report server's instance.  When I checked, I find one subscription that had a "contains parameter values that are not valid", and it was due to an old version of a location name that was stored.  So taking a gander there could give a little more information.

Comment: the parameters are populated by a query when the report is loaded; there are quite a few other reports in our PROD environment which use this same structure/technique; it's hard to imagine that a "value that isn't there" would be the issue

Comment: I looked at the report.  It doesn't apply the available values as default values, so--in a sense--SSRS is reverting back to the original form overnight.  When I'm in the subscription screen, I thought I could override those settings.  Is that not the case?  (Actually, it works when I set the time to be a few minutes later--it just fails when I set it overnight.)<br/>  \n
Edit: It was bitnine's comment that made me go look at the original report.  He(?) was right about the parameter value in the subscription table: empty.  
why can't I make a new line?